# Popup is displaying from wrong place on leaflet map in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, leaflet, latitude-longitude

Basically I have some table with places, and I want to open a popup when clicked on this place. Problem is that the popup opens but not exactly at given position, but it is moved (like 1km or so). Only on Internet Explorer (11), and only on some points.

```
function openPopup(lat, lng, str){
  map.panTo([lat, lng]);
  var popup = L.popup()
  .setLatLng([lat, lng])
  .setContent(str)
  .openOn(map);
}

 openPopup(50.1143951416016,14.4470748901367,'Povltavska');
```

What I've tried:

1. Downloading a new version of leaflet (7.2.5), it didn't fixed it.
2. Updating IE. Still the same.
3. I've tried a simple clicking and creating a pop-up, that works well:

   function onMapClick(e) {
     popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " +e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);}map.on('click', onMapClick);

Has someone already experienced this? Could you give me please some hint why some points are not at their position?

Comment: Same is happening for me, the popup is waaay further north above it's marker than it should be. Only in IE 8,9. Haven't checked in 10, works fine in 11